# Determine in a VSTO addin if a user is currently "using" Excel 2007

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, vsto

I am currently writing a VSTO addin for Excel 2007 on a Windows 7 machine.

I have implemented a Windows.Forms.NativeWindow and Window HotKey in order to know when a user hits a certain key combination. This all works fine, whenever the key combination is pressed it is detected in the winProc.

My VSTO is getting a message that the key combination has been pressed, but now I need to actually know if the user is "using" Excel.  I suppose I want to know if Excel is on the top or they are somewhere in Excel in a cell.

I thought that the ActiveSheet / ActiveWorkbook or ActiveCell objects of the Application object would help but they seem to be always something even when I am working in another application and use the key combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this code being used by me in a few VSTO addins.

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" Alias "GetForegroundWindow" () As Integer

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        If GetForegroundWindow() = Application.Hwnd Then
            MsgBox("on top")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

End Class
```

So you can use GetForegroundWindow and Application.Hwnd to get the information that Excel is on the Top of Z-order. Code is in VB.net and can be easily converted to c#.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It looks to work in my test so far. I'm doing this in VB.net so it was perfect.